# Signing for "GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn" requires a development team

Tags: swift, xcode

After updating to Xcode 14 I'm getting the following error:

```
Signing for "GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.`
```

I've tried doing pod update but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issue after switching to Xcode 14. Add this to your podfile and call `pod install`. This will permanently fix the issue.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do we really need this loop twice: `target.build_configurations.each do |config|`?

Comment: OK, this fixes my problem but could you give us some more context why this solves the issue, please? I would like to learn from it and copy-pasting from here is going to solve my problem but also is going to shrink my brain lol

Comment: Thank you, @Vahagn. You saved me so much headache

Comment: Or simply use [`CocoaPods-pod-sign`](https://github.com/1677/CocoaPods-pod-sign).

Comment: Iulian Onofrei this tool seems like a useful resource, but do you think it might be a bit excessive to utilize a third-party tool simply for the purpose of adding a few lines of code to the podfile?

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your podfile and call **pod install**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
        config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

From the target POD Select

> GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn

then go to the team drop list and select your team

[image]

Comment: This will be required every time after doing pod install, for permanent fix it's better to add a post_install script

Comment: exactly yes for best practices add it to POD script.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you update to the latest React Native version (at time of writing: `v0.70.3`) to get their fix (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34673) for the code signing change to XCode14

You can check your latest react native package version with `yarn list --pattern react-native` in your project root

After updating either:

1. update `ios/Podfile` with the following

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
        config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

where `YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID` is replaced with the actual value

or

2. Manually go through the pods failing the build and select your development team and re-attempt building.

Answer (score 0):

For me, for my flutter project after upgrading my Xcode:

1. Open ios->Podfile
2. Remove the function from "post_install"
3. Add the below code.

**Note: Do not forget to change your Development Team Code**.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
         config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_CODE'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify which function you mean in step #2?

Answer (score 0):

It is working on my flutter project

- Please, don't select a team, you don't need it
- remove "Pods" folder (project_name>ios>Pods)
- remove "Podfile.lock" file (project_name>ios>Podfile.lock)
- open "Podfile" file (project_name>ios>Podfile) and change

  ```
    post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end end
  ```

to =>

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

- Open terminal

> pod install